# How to count with two "HAVING" situation in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to count how many id_no does have *ALL line_number* with *test_activity = approved* and *test_status = completed* and filtered by *work_type which is B*.

```
id  id _no  line_number   work_type   date        test_activity     test_status
P   P-01       1               b      2020-02-02    approved          completed
P   P-01       2               b      2020-02-02    approved          completed
P   P-01       3               b      2020-02-02    approved          completed
P   P-02       4               b      2020-02-02    approved          incompleted
P   P-02       5               b      2020-02-02    approved          incompleted
P   P-02       6               b      2020-02-02    approved          completed
Q   Q-01       7               b      2020-02-02    in progress       incompleted
Q   Q-01       8               b      2020-02-02    in progress       incompleted
Q   Q-01       9               b      2020-02-02    not started       incompleted
Q   Q-02      10               b      2020-02-02    approved          completed
Q   Q-02      11               b      2020-02-02    approved          completed
Q   Q-02      12               b      2020-02-02    approved          completed
```

I tried:

```
select date, count(*) as count
from (select id, id_no, date
      from pt_pretest pp where work_type = 'b'
      group by id, id_no, date 
      having min(test_activity) = max(test_activity) and min(test_activity ) = 'approved'
      and having min(test_status) = max(test_status) and min(test_status) = 'completed'
      ) as x group by date
```

But it did not work. From the sample above, the expected result is:

```
id   date         count
P    2020-02-02     1
Q    2020-02-02     1
```

How should I write my query so I will the expected result?

Thankyou

Comment: What does "But it did not work" mean? Did you get an error? If so, which error message? Or did you get an unexpected result? If so, in which way was it different from what you expected?

Comment: And what is it you really want to count? You say you want to count how many id_no are approved/completed only. But then you also group by id and date. And then you create a query that counts such id_no per date. And then you show an expected result that does not only contain a date, but also an id. That is four different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one `having` too many in your query. Remove it.

```
select id, id_no, date, count(*)
from pt_pretest pp
where work_type = 'b'
group by id, id_no, date 
having min(test_activity) = max(test_activity) and min(test_activity ) = 'approved'
   and min(test_status) = max(test_status) and min(test_status) = 'completed'
order by id, id_no, date;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following returns all ids that have at least one `id_no` that fails the condition:

```
select id, count(*)
from (select id, id_no
      from t
      where not (test_activity = 'approved' and test_status = 'completed')
      group by id, id_no
     ) ii
group by id;
```

If you want zeros in the result set, use conditional aggregation in the subquery:

```
select id, count( num_bad > 0 )
from (select id, id_no,
             sum( not (test_activity = 'approved' and test_status = 'completed') ) as num_bad
      from t
      group by id, id_no
     ) ii
group by id;
```